# How to add column in installed application dataBase

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have win form application and installed with Visual studio  OneClick publish. In one click publish solution if we send update then I delete the database and installed it from new and we lose our all information that store in a database. That is why I have created a database in another folder so that it will in touch it when we send an update. 
But my problem is that if I would like to change that database, for example, to add one more column in a table then how I can implement that.

Comment: Your question will not get good answers as it stands.  No idea what you are trying to do.  SQLite is a file.  You connect to it, run a statement.  If that's not a good enough answer, then you have to do a better job of explaining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear to answer.

Are you creating a setup project? and want to update new database structure changes to update already installed database?

If so, I recommend to create a Updater project separately. which will automatically check the version of your application/database with the version on the sever.

**Updater Project EXE**
First of all you need to store the new scripts in a table in your server, with associated application version number say 1.0.0.1 (columns separately for each)

while your main application run, at the startup run this `Updater.exe` to check any new version from the server(hosted). if current version is lower then that of the server then download the scripts related to that version and do update the local database with newly downloaded main exe which will replace existing one. not the updater.exe

This was just hints how you can do it.

you may need some **Web API or Web service or WCF service** to do that.